# Reload UITableview data in cell out of view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, reload

```
[self.countryList reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; // or NO ;)
```

My problem is that I have a tableview with 10+ items with only 6 cells in view, but when the data is loaded and the table is scrolled cell 7 has no data in it. How can I reload the data in that 1 cell?

The code above is what I am using and it doesn't work!

---EDIT---

```
if (cell == nil) {  

    cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
    //[cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];




    mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(52.0, 0.0, 200.0, 20.0)] autorelease];           
    mainLabel.tag = 1;          
    mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];            
    mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;          
    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mainLabel.opaque = YES;
    mainLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

    revenue = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(52.0, 20.0, 150.0, 20.0)] autorelease];            
    revenue.tag = 3;            
    revenue.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];          
    revenue.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;            
    revenue.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    revenue.opaque = YES;
    revenue.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:revenue];

    promos = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(252.0, 20.0, 150.0, 20.0)] autorelease];            
    promos.tag = 4;         
    promos.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];           
    promos.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;         
    promos.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    promos.opaque = YES;
    promos.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:promos];

    updates = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(252.0, 0.0, 200.0, 20.0)] autorelease];            
    updates.tag = 5;            
    updates.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];          
    updates.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;            
    updates.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    updates.opaque = YES;
    updates.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:updates];

    photo = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)] autorelease];
    photo.contentMode= UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    photo.tag = 2;
    photo.opaque = YES;
    photo.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:photo]; 

}    
else {
    cell.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
    mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];    
    photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    promos=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    revenue=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    updates=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];


    if(photo.image){
        photo.image=nil;
    }
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageURL =[NSString stringWithString:[(arrayResults*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] myCountryIcon]];

    NSArray *myArray = [imageURL componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithString:[myArray lastObject]];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/AppIcons"];
    NSString* path = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (!image) {

        UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        // Create an array with the URL and name.  
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:fileName,imageURL, nil  ];  


        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:)  withObject:arr]; 
        [arr release];


    }               
    else{
        photo.image=image;


    }
    NSString*promostext=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"promos:%@",[[(arrayResults*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mypromos]stringValue] ];
    NSString*revenuetext=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"revenue:%@",[(arrayResults*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] myrevenue] ];
    NSString*updatestext=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"updates:%@",[[(arrayResults*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] myupdates]stringValue] ];

    mainLabel.text=[(arrayResults*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] myCountryName];
    promos.text=promostext;
    revenue.text=revenuetext;
    updates.text=updatestext;
    [promostext release];
    [revenuetext release];
    [updatestext release];

}
```

Comment: It is likely to be your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: that is at fault here.  Can you post your code?

Comment: What about the rest of it? Where do you actually put text in the labels, and images in the image views?

Comment: sorry i did it in haste lol,  i must add i am using the same code in another app and i don't have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically a misuse in the recycle/reuse mechanism of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Cells are reused when you scroll to avoid allocating too much UITableViewCells. So you need to set the content of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in both case, either if the cell just have been allocated (cell==nil) or if the cell has been reused (cell!=nil).

Comment: so why would cells 1-6 and 8-10 load and not 7? i must add i am using the same code in another app and i don't have this problem

Comment: Exactly for the reason I explained. Because these first cells are allocated and you fill their content in the `cell==nil` case (as there is no existing `UITableViewCell` already allocated but not used and reusable, so `dequeueCellWithIdentifier` returns `nil`), but when you scroll, those cells are reused (recycled) to display the other content, so in this case you go in the `cell!=nil` case, where there probably is a problem in your code there. Put breakpoints in your code to understand better exactly which path in the code are executed in both case.

Comment: Especially you should fill the content of your labels, imageviews, etc (and everything that changes between one cell and another) **outside** the `if` statement, to fill the cell in both cases, whereas these cells have been recycled or just allocated.